# Direct download of Docker-CE installation packages

Tags: docker, installation

Docker requires login to the "Hub" to access downloads to installation packages.

How can I download the latest builds on Windows and Mac without registering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Direct download](https://download.docker.com) links are available from Docker.

Windows: https://download.docker.com/win/stable/Docker%20for%20Windows%20Installer.exe

Mac: https://download.docker.com/mac/edge/Docker.dmg

For Linux, see: https://download.docker.com/linux/

---

*Other methods*

Windows-Chocolatey:

```
choco install docker-desktop
```

Mac Homebrew

```
brew cask install docker       # Install Docker
open /Applications/Docker.app  # Start Docker
```

WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux):

https://gist.github.com/rstacruz/297fc799f094f55d062b982f7dac9e41#windows

---

Read the full discussion here (my source): https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/6910

Further reading: https://gist.github.com/rstacruz/297fc799f094f55d062b982f7dac9e41